# jQuery draggable and Firefox Issue

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox

Kindly note that when using jquery UI draggable with Firefox v13.0.1, i am not able to edit the textboxes.

Sample code : [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/saravanan/gsebN/8/)

Is there a workaround for this issue.

jQuery: 1.7.1, jQuery UI: 1.8.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're calling `disableSelection()` on all columns. This results in mouse clicks not being received by the `<input>` elements.

Removing that call fixes your problem. You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gsebN/9/).

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great. Since i am new to jquery ui i did not get what it really meant.